# How to get around the saved $_POST variables in PHP?

Tags: php, email, post, csv

So basically, I am creating a bulk email application that is super small for personal use.

It has a very small form that consists of only an upload button for a CSV file, and a drop down list for the subject of the email. Each email is taken from the CSV file, saved in an array, and run through a loop to be processed and sent.

I am only running this when $_POST 'submit' is set. Although, upon page reload/refresh, the emails are all sent again without the submit button even being pressed since the $_POST variable is still set/existing.

I would post all my code here, although it is slightly large. If desperately needed, I may be able to shorten it and post it here.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Google for `nonce`'s: basically a hidden token in a form which can only be used _once_, and the action isn't taken a second time because your `nonce` is no longer valid. So: create random value, add to session, add as hidden input, on receiving: look for it in the session, remove it if found & take action, if not found: don't take action.

Comment: @Wrikken - Any chance you could give an example of this? Currently not using a session.

Comment: @JohnConde - Not using C#, so this question is quite different and is asking for a way around (example of) the `$_POST` variable in PHP.

Comment: Post/redirect/get has nothing to do with what language you're using. Click on the link in my answer.

Comment: Also, see this article for a PHP example http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168

Comment: @fizzix: http://tyleregeto.com/article/a-guide-to-nonce

Comment: But: John's answer is quite valid for most cases, nonces _may_ be overkill, in 'normal browsing' the 'always redirect / force a GET request after a POST' takes care of _most_ problems.

Comment: @fizzix see "alternate approach one" in my answer for an example f how to use a nonce/number used once. Here I'm using "sha1(rand())" to create the "number" which is actually a large random hex string, ensuring that you never get the same number twice unless you run it millions of times a second for hundreds of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the HTTP protocol is designed to work, though most GUI web browsers will warn a user with some kind of "are you sure you want to resubmit data?" message.

In order to avoid t his situation, our policy is to never send any page back to the browser on a POST request. We always process the data and then use header('location:') to redirect to a GET request displaying the results.

For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
 /* process post data */

  header('Location: done.html');
  exit;
}
```

Basically this makes it impossible for the user to refresh the page, because refreshing will refresh "done.html" instead of the POST request.

If you're sending a lot of emails though, they might refresh the page while you are sending emails. To solve that I would take one of two approaches:

**Alternate approach one**, use a log to avoid duplicates:

instead of "submit=1" use something like `<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="<?php echo sha1(rand()); ?>">`

Then, your php script records the value and complains if it ever gets used twice:

```
if (file_exists('./'.$_POST['submit'])) {
  die('do not refresh!');
}
file_put_contents('./'.$_POST['submit'], '1'); // TODO: make sure a hacker doesn't put a different path in 'submit' allowing them to write to your server's filesystem... just check if there are any '/' characters in $_POST['submit']
```

**Alternate approach two:**

Save every email you need to send to a mysql database, with a "sent" boolean. As you send each email set that boolean to true. Do not ever send an email where the boolean is false. This is a lot more work, but it is the "proper" approach if you are willing to spend the time building a stable system where you need to be certain you will never annoy your customers with duplicate emails.

Probably a better idea than using this approach is to sign up for a free service such as MailChimp and get them to do the emails for you.

Comment: But what if I need to refresh the page to use to application again with new data?

Comment: Then just redirect to the page with the *new* data.

Comment: Your alternative approach one seems logical, and I might give that a try. Is there any way to unset a $_POST variable?

Comment: Although, forcing the page to not refresh is not ideal since I will need to run the application a few times with different CSV files...

Comment: post variabels aren't saved anywhere. it's the web browser that is storing it and sending it again when you refresh. the server cannot tell the browser to clear it

Comment: you just have to create the "nonce" (sha1(rand())) again every time a new CSV file is provided.

Comment: You should also consider just using MailChimp or something. Sending emails is a *hard* problem because of spam. Unless you really know what you're doing, you will have problems where your messages are treated as if they are spam.